# Ngrok outgoing requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ngrok

I'm using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to forward my development env. I've added [custom domains (white label URLs)](https://ngrok.com/docs#custom-domains) and configured the CNAME (example: mycustomdomain.com). I need to request some server with url (example: a.com/whitelisted). The server has a whitelisting where multiple url's are being stored (this list also contains our mycustomdomain.com), the server checks each incoming request with the whitelisting document and the certificate.

So basically we want something like this:

```
                                                          XXXXXXX
                                                         X        X
+--------+              +------------+                  XX        XX
|        |              |            |                 XX          XX
|        --------------->            | -------------> X   Internet   X
|        |              |            |                X              X
+--------+              +------------+                 XX           XX
                                                        XX        XX
 localhost                Ngrok server                     X     X
                                                           XXXXXXX
```

Now I figured out that we can do something like [this](https://ngrok.com/docs#tls) with Ngrok:
`./ngrok tls -region=eu -hostname=mycustomdomain.com -key mykey.key -crt mycert.crt 3005`

But I'm not quite sure regarding the outgoing request to the server, because for example I can't just make a simple HTTP request, because that will come from my development env and not from the Ngrok with all the configured/required stuff. Does anyone have experience with such use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a proxy, not a reverse proxy like ngrok.

ngrok can forward requests to your development server but it isn't involved with outgoing requests from your development server.

Alternatively if you control the server you're looking to reach from your development server, you could have ngrok act as a reverse proxy on behalf of that server and proxy your requests through ngrok with IP whitelisted tunnel authentication.